# Connection closed by foreign host while using telnet

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I am developing push notification first time and came across this telnet command:
    `telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195`

I get following response by using this command

```
Trying 17.172.233.151...
Connected to gateway.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'
```

but after approx 30 sec,It shows like **"Connection closed by foreign host"** so I am confused whether my server is connected to Apple Push Notification Server or not!

Any help would be greatly appreciated,Thanks!

Comment: have you checked if your `port 2195` isn't blocked by your firewall?

Comment: 2195 and 2196 port are enable in server

Comment: what's your server environment? Windows or Linux? I checked `gateway.push.apple.com 2195` both in windows and linux, it works.

Comment: does this also occur in `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195` ?

Comment: It's Linux and yes getting same thing for sandbox.

Comment: try this instead `openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195`

Comment: if it returns like `CONNECTED(00000003)`, then it is working. Don't worry about the **failed handshake** or the **unable to get local issuer certificate** because we are just testing if you're able to connect successfully in the apns

Comment: Yes getting this, CONNECTED(00000003)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1). Once you've got the necessary certificates, use this to test if you can successfully connect to the apns:

`openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem`

**NOTE:** if you've encountered an error like `error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate`, just download [entrust_2048_ca.cer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiE56TJtL3KAhXD5KYKHTavAMMQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.entrust.net%2Fdownloads%2Fbinary%2Fentrust_2048_ca.cer&usg=AFQjCNGn2KGZhTvdkLw2KKEdbYrUyvhFFA&sig2=f0EUuqKw452z7UsEa-QGHg&cad=rja), and together with the other certificates, you can check it like this:

`openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem -CAfile entrust_2048_ca.cer`